# unable to turn a simple text file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, error-handling

this is what my file looks like:

`raw_file` -->

```
'Date\tValue\tSeries\tLabel\n07/01/2007\t687392\t31537611\tThis home\n08/01/2007\t750624\t31537611\tThis home\n09/01/2007\t769358\t31537611\tThis home\n10/01/2007\t802014\t31537611\tThis home\n11/01/2007\t815973\t31537611\tThis home\n12/01/2007\t806853\t31537611\tThis home\n01/01/2008\t836318\t31537611\tThis home\n02/01/2008\t856792\t31537611\tThis home\n03/01/2008\t854411\t31537611\tThis home\n04/01/2008\t826354\t31537611\tThis home\n05/01/2008\t789017\t31537611\tThis home\n06/01/2008\t754162\t31537611\tThis home\n07/01/2008\t749522\t31537611\tThis home\n08/01/2008\t757577\t31537611\tThis home\n'
```

`type(raw_file)` --> `<type 'str'>`

for some reason, `I can't use pd.read_csv(raw_file)` or I would get the error:

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 710, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)
IOError: File Date  Value   Series  Label
07/01/2007  687392  31537611    This home
08/01/2007  750624  31537611    This home
does not exist
```

the best I can think of is :

```
for row in raw_file.split('\n'):
   print(row.split('\t'))
```

which is quite slow. is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `csv` module and set the delimiter to `\t`?

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

with csv.reader(your_file, delimiter='\t') as f:
    # Do stuff

Answer (score 0):

when you give pandas a `string` as a `filepath_or_buffer` parameter - it thinks it's a filename or an URL.

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **filepath_or_buffer** : `str`, `pathlib.Path`, `py._path.local.LocalPath` or any object with a `read()` method (such as a file `handle` or `StringIO`)
>
> The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3,
>   and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local
>
> file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.csv

Solution: use `io.StringIO()` constructor:

```
In [69]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw_file), delim_whitespace=True)
Out[69]:
              Date     Value Series Label
07/01/2007  687392  31537611   This  home
08/01/2007  750624  31537611   This  home
09/01/2007  769358  31537611   This  home
10/01/2007  802014  31537611   This  home
11/01/2007  815973  31537611   This  home
12/01/2007  806853  31537611   This  home
01/01/2008  836318  31537611   This  home
02/01/2008  856792  31537611   This  home
03/01/2008  854411  31537611   This  home
04/01/2008  826354  31537611   This  home
05/01/2008  789017  31537611   This  home
06/01/2008  754162  31537611   This  home
07/01/2008  749522  31537611   This  home
08/01/2008  757577  31537611   This  home
```